# A "boiling" question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just stumbled over the thing again today, so I did some search and came to nothing conclusive, thus I thought about asking here on Skeptics. But, first, I'd like to know if it is a question that can fit the rules.

> Subject: Hot water boilers.
>
> Half of the world claim that it's better to keep them always on.
>   The other half, that it should be turned on and off following necessity.
>
> Half of Internet agree with the second claim. The other half with the
>   first.
>
> I can't find any number, as simply as it should be taking a boiler and
>   measuring its power consumption in both cases.
>
> Can one of the two above claims be scientifically proved?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this question as it stands.

The first is that it is vague - it doesn't define what "better" means.

I have lived in a house with a switch in the fusebox to allow you to choose between them. Our decision was never based on optimal power consumption. It was based on how much consumption was expected during the day, versus the electricity company charging lower rates for overnight hot water heaters, to allow them to remain competitive with the gas company.

The way we would normal resolve this would be to look at the the context of the original claim to see what the people making the original claim meant by better. That brings us to the second, more serious problem. There are no links to people making the claim. You should find some examples and include links to them (and quote them to protect against link rot.)

Comment: Sorry, it is so widely discussed since so many years across all the internet and real life that, you are right, I totally forgot to specify what I was speaking about...I feel an idiot now :-D Better in term of power consumption.